# How to ack a message from different Channel of RabbitTemplate?

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

Suppose I have single rabbitTemplate instance,  and I call rabbitTemplate.send（Message）to publishe a message to RabbitMQ server.

What I want to do here are:
1. from publisher view , how to make sure the message is received by RabbitMQ ?
2. In the consumer side, I use the same rabbitTemplate to receive message in a thread, and I want to manually ack the message in the other thread.

Is there any way to manually ack the message by RabbitTemplate?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 3):

1. RabbitMQ is asynchronous so there's no way to "wait" for the message to be secured in the broker; you can enable publisher confirms to get confirmation that a message was delivered to a queue. See the [documentation for more information](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/current/reference/html/amqp.html#d4e413).
2. You can't manually ack the message when using one of the `receive*()` methods; you would have to drop down to the native API by using the `execute()` method; in the callback, perform  `channel.basicGet(queue, false)` to receive the message and then `channel.basicAck(deliveryTag)`.

Comment: Thank you and more questions about Channel and deliveryTag.                                 I receive a message from Channel by invoke rabbitTemplate.receive*, and I store deliveryTag of this message. This step rabbitTemplate close the Channel, and no ACK occured by config MANUAL acknowledge mode. In another thread, I process the message and return processing result. finally, I create a new Channel, by the same rabbitTemplate, to ack or nack stored deliveryTag. But I find that the ack take no effect. What happens?

Comment: After searching doc and debugging code, I find that deviveryTag is channel specific. So when I ack message using the different channel, the ACK take no effect, even though no exception is catched.            I'd better re declare what I want to do.                              1.client poll message from rabbitmq.                                   2.task executor run a new thread to process message.                       3.ACK or NACK message rely on messsage processing result.            How can I to do that? Thanks again.

Comment: You can't do that. You must ack messages on the same channel. Why don't you use a [Listener Container](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/1.3.5.RELEASE/reference/html/amqp.html#async-consumer) instead? Then the framework will take care of your acks.

Comment: Thanks for your advise. ChannelAwareMessageListener can manually ACK message indeed. What I want here is a client-poll style consumer, which can give me more options. For example, when task thread pool is full, I do not pull message from RabbitMQ and just wait for next loop. MessageListener is a server-push style consumer, and I can't stop to receiving message even if I know task thread pool is over busy.

Comment: one more question about Channel. If channel is accidental closed， Is't there a way to create "the same channel" to ACK message?

Comment: Right, but with the listener, you control the concurrency with the container (`concurrent-consumers`) you don't need/use a second thread pool; you don't need manual ack, let the container's thread perform the ack when you are done. No you can't "reopen" a channel - if it is closed, the message will be put back on the queue at that tha time.

Comment: Thank you for your advise. Let the container's thread perform the ack and run the business task in MessageListener thread, If my business run failed, how to info the container to reject message?

Comment: After debugging code, I find that the container will reject message If I throw a Exception in MessageListener thread. Thanks Gary Russell. My problem is solved.